# Angular- find Children component name

Tags: angular, routes, components

i have a parent component with a breadcrumb component and a router-outlet:

```
<div class="LG_popage-wrap">
  <div class="LG_global-popage-crumbs" style="text-align: center">
    <app-breadcrumb [breadcrumbsData]="breadcrumb" ></app-breadcrumb>
  </div>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

The breadcrumb attributes is just a array on component name:

```
  breadcrumb: Array<BreadcrumbModel> = [
    {
      componentName: 'StepSetupComponent',
      label: 'setup'
    },
    {
      componentName: 'StepFieldsComponent',
      label: 'fields'
    },
  ]
```

I need in my children route (injected with router Outlet), compare the name of the current component name with my array.
I already code that but its work only in local not in production

```
export class BreadcrumbComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() breadcrumbsData: Array<BreadcrumbModel> = [];
  breadcrumbsIndex: number;
  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router
  ) {
    router.events.subscribe((val) => {
      // Route changing
      window.scrollTo(0, 0);

      this.breadcrumbsIndex = this.breadcrumbsData.findIndex(x => x.componentName === this.route.firstChild.component['name']);
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.breadcrumbsIndex = this.breadcrumbsData.findIndex(x => x.componentName === this.route.firstChild.component['name']);
  }

}
```

The probleme is this.route.firstChild.component['name']

In local he gives me the name of the component.
But In prod he gives me the name "N"

how can I find the name of my current component ?

thanks you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

On building your project angular makes your codes uglify for smaller bundle size. because of that the names will be changed.

Also it is not the right way to handle breadcrumbs. Try to add your label to the route data and get it there